# Unresolved reference in Python class

Tags: python, oop

This is my code:

```
class robot:
    def __init__(givenName,givenColor):
        self.name=givenName//error
        self.color=givenColor//error
    def intro(self):
        print("my name izz "+self.name)

r1=robot();
r1.name='tom'
r1.color='red'

r2=robot();
r2.name='blue'
r2.color='blue'
r1.intro()
r2.intro()
```

I am getting an error in the above commented lines. I know this question has many answers on stackoverflow but none seems to work .  [the function calls self.color and self.color give the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNc4i.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `__init__` should be `self`:

```
def __init__(self, givenName, givenColor):
    self.name = givenName
    self.color = givenColor
```

Otherwise, your code will fail as `self` will not be accessible within the method.

You have 2 options to define attributes:

**Option 1**

Define at initialization with `__init__` as above. For example:

```
r1 = robot('tom', 'red')
```

**Option 2**

Do not define at initialization, in which case these arguments must be optional:

```
class robot:
    def __init__(self, givenName='', givenColor=''):
        self.name=givenName
        self.color=givenColor
    def intro(self):
        print("my name izz "+self.name)

r1 = robot()

r1.givenName = 'tom'
r1.givenColor = 'red'
```

Comment: Also, `r1 = robot()` will fail because it's expecting to receive 2 arguments, i.e. `givenName` and `givenColor`. You should be doing `r1 = robot('tom', 'red')` instead.

Comment: it worked. the first solution that included adding self at the beginning of the constructor worked.